# Force subfolders to follow parent htaccess redirect rules?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am currently using the following `.htaccess` code on my server to enable me to host the primary domain files from a subfolder in the `public_html` folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory/index.php [L]
```

This doesn't solve the problem of subfolders of this new root, however. For example, I have two folders:

`public_html\example\` - which should correspond to **www.example.com**

and

`public_html\example\subfolder` - which should correspond to **www.example.com/subfolder**

My problem is that navigating to **www.example.com/subfolder** in the browser redirects me to **www.example.com/example/subfolder**.

**EDIT**: Further to the response from @Jon, this is only occurring when navigating to the URL *without* a trailing slash. Navigating to **www.example.com/subfolder/** is working as expected.

How do I prevent the redirect to www.example.com/**example**/subfolder?

Comment: This is almost impossible to follow.  The backslashes don't help. Be more clear about URL's and filesystem paths and what you observe vs. expect.

Comment: Thanks @covener, I've edited the question to make it easier to follow. Let me know if it makes more sense.

Comment: how does subdirectory relate to subfolder in the example?

Comment: Does it actually redirect? There are no [R] flags or Redirect directives.  What do you actualyl observe?

Comment: I expect to see the index.php file that is in `public_html\example\subfolder` when I navigate to www.example.com/subfolder, but navigating there causes the browser to navigate to www.example.com/example/subfolder. I essentially need the `.htaccess` file to completely hide the fact that the domain is running from the /example/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to a URL that's a folder and you are missing the trailing slash, apache will *redirect* the browser to so that there's a trailing slash at the end. This can sometimes mess with rewrite rules that are internally rewriting requests.

You either must go to `example.com/subfolder/` or turn off the directory slash function. However, [turning this off can be very dangerous](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash):

> **Security Warning**
>
> Turning off the trailing slash redirect may result in an information disclosure. Consider a situation where mod_autoindex is active (Options +Indexes) and DirectoryIndex is set to a valid resource (say, index.html) and there's no other special handler defined for that URL. In this case a request with a trailing slash would show the index.html file. **But a request without trailing slash would list the directory contents**.

This means, if someone goes to: `example.com/subfolder`, they'll see your directory contents, eventhough there's an index.php file there. You can turn off indexes but then they'll just see a 403, and still won't see your index.php.

Comment: Oh wow, this is the issue that is occuring. Navigating to **www.example.com/subfolder/** keeps the browser on the same page, but **www.example.com/subfolder** without the trailing slash is causing the redirect.